# Errors with AnyEvent in Windows Perl

Tags: perl, fork, anyevent

I try to use AnyEvent's fork_call in Windows Perl. I wrote some sample code:

```
use AnyEvent;
use AnyEvent::Util;
use Data::Dumper;

my $cv = AnyEvent -> condvar;
my $a;

fork_call {
    $a = 1;
    $cv -> send;
}, sub {
    $cv -> recv;
    print Dumper $a;
}
```

But I got following error:

```
Can't locate object method "one_event" via package "AnyEvent" at
C:/Perl/perl/site/lib/AnyEvent/Util.pm line 329.
END failed--call queue aborted.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is wrong. If you using `fork()` then you'll have copy of `$cv` and `$a`. Right code is:

```
use AnyEvent;
use AnyEvent::Util;

my $cv = AnyEvent->condvar;
my $a;

fork_call {
    1;
} sub {
    ($a) = @_;
    print($a);
    $cv->send();
};
$cv->wait();
```